# No sound over headphones on a new Samsung Notebook 7 Force

Tags: sound, kubuntu, headphones, 19.10

I bought a new notebook and I'm having a hard time figuring out why it won't output sound over my wired headphones. The notebook is the Samsung Notebook 7 Force and I'm running Kubuntu 19.10.

It recognizes them as plugged in and `pavucontrol` display things as if the sound is being reproduced. There is nothing muted on `alsamixer` also. Sound work fine with the onboard speakers.

I also noticed that the driver searcher thingy in Settings doesn't show a list of hardware components, it only displays a message saying is getting information about the system (I don't know if it is related, I just thought it could have something to do with missing drivers).

Being a Dell user since, well, forever, I really thought wonky hardware support was a thing of the past.

`sudo lshw -c multimedia`output:

```
       *-usb:3                   
       description: Video
       product: 720p HD Camera
       vendor: Generic
       physical id: 6
       bus info: usb@1:6
       version: 0.06
       serial: 200901010001
       capabilities: usb-2.01
       configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
  *-multimedia
       description: Audio device
       product: Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
       version: 11
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:600-5ff irq:139 
       memory:6013118000-601311bfff memory:6013000000-60130fffff
```

**EDIT:**

By setting the volume at 100% I can hear some sound: it is very low and it's played distorted, kinda like a buzzing sound.

**EDIT 2:**

HDMI output doesn't work also. [This guy is having the same problem](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=303303) (S51 Pro is the model name of this laptop in Brazil).

Comment: Same problem on Samsung np760xbe. Another thread related: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-laptop-and-netbook-25/headphone-jack-woes-on-samsung-notebook-7-force-4175668909/ . Kernel 5.3.0-40-generic and Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: yes, the same laptop and the link you posted is yet another thread started by me =)

Comment: Is your headphone jack compatible with your laptop. e.g. 3.5mm or 4.5mm

Comment: It's 3,5 mm and I have tested a bunch of headphones, it's not the hardware, since it works on Windows. I've been almost five months stuck on this - and some - issues with this laptop with little help. I'm not trying to diagnose it or fix it anymore because I can't afford the time any longer. I did got back to Windows, unfortunately.

Comment: @wowbagger, can you try this? `echo "options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-dock" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/axr-audio.conf` . Seems that the audio will work, but I'm not certain about the microphone.

Comment: There are a lot of discussions about this problem in different places (not a final solution yet): https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-laptop-and-netbook-25/headphone-jack-woes-on-samsung-notebook-7-force-4175668909/ and https://www.linux.org/threads/samsung-notebook-7-force-headphone-jack-and-keyboard-lighting-issues.27304/#post-87920 and https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=279424&start=40 and https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1898849#p1898849

Comment: About the HDMI, it works but you will suffer to setup the nvidia driver. This notebook has hybrid graphics (two GPUs: intel and nvidia) and, like other notebooks on the market, this combination is painful for Linux. About the headphone, I gave up and I bought a USB sound card (Ugreen).

Answer (score 0):

**Pain is over!**

```
sudo apt install alsa-tools-gui
```

1. Then, open HDAJACKRETASK
2. Switch to REALTEK ALC256
3. On "Black Mic Right Side" Check "Override" and select "Dock Microphone"
4. Click Apply now (error message pops up)
5. Install boot override
6. Reboot

[hdajack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMyQc.png)

Tried on Elementary OS.

When headset is connected go to sound options and just select proper options to use input/output from it.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, this doesn't work on the 20.04. Which, by the way, also doesn't work with the Intel Bluetooth/Wi-Fi combo card because reasons. So, yeah, Windows sadly.

Answer (score 0):

I found just a simple solution
Just when connect on the jack go on the sound settings
go to input and select the mic of headphone.
Whoo Ha!
That's work
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWesV.png)

Just registed to post the solution. Hope its works on you case too.