# Asus Zenbook jack problem

Tags: audio-jack

I just got an asus ux430unr and I have managed to configure dual boot on it (windows and ubuntu).
Unfortunately, I ran into a sound problem, the speakers work perfectly but the audio jack (3.5) doesn't work on ubuntu, works perfectly on windows but on ubuntu, it doesn't produce sound and when I move the jack a little (in or out) it makes a weird crackling sound.
can anybody help me with this issue, I use the jack so often while working and I use ubuntu for work!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so excuse me for not exactly answering your question. But I have some insight on this because [I'm facing the same problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183863/no-sound-over-headphones-on-a-new-samsung-notebook-7-force) with a Samsung Notebook 7 Force on Ubuntu 19.10. So I have some points:

- Did you tried to up the volume to the limit? On mine, if you do this,
  you can hear the sound being played veeeery faint and distorted.
- I also noticed that on the Samsung the HDMI output doesn't work

I'm sure those problems are related to drivers and quirks yet to be supported. It's important to report these issues so that they get fixed.

Comment: Turning up the volume does absolutely nothing and I did not try hdmi, I don't have a monitor or tv to try that unfortunately, so maybe if someone has the same issue and tests that, we would be thankful for him ^^